# Getting "null" in Membership.GetUser() and Page.Identity.User

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have implemented the ASPNET membership provider and at the `Login1_LoggedIn` event, I tried to get `Membership.GetUser()` or `Page.Identity.User` but both of them returned null.

I tried different solutions suggested by others including changing form `path="/"` but have no luck. However the `LoginName` control works and showing the `username` correctly.

Does anyone has an idea why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found out why, ScottGu has explained it well in his blog post.

http://forums.asp.net/t/982749.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable non-authenticated users in web.config:

```
<authorization>
   <deny users="?" />
</authorization>
```

the HttpContext.Current.User will not pupulated until you call :

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(UserName, False)
```

or

```
FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(UserName, False)
```